# In MongoDB, is it better to dissociate Schemas or put them together?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

Take the example of a Story : a story is compose of many sentences in my case the story will never exceed 20 sentences. 
It is better to make a schema for a Story and an another one for the  Sentences and finally make in Story a reference to the sentences which compose the story :

```
var SentenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // Some other fields ...

  sentence: {
      type: String,
      validate: validateSentence,
      trim: true
  }

  // Some other fields ...

});    

var StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // Some other fields ...

  //Sentences of the Story
  sentences: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Sentence'
  }]

  // Some other fields ...

});
```

Or is it better to put sentences directly in story :

```
var StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // Some other fields ...

  //Sentences of the Story
  sentences: [{

    // Some other fields ...

    sentence: {
        type: String,
        validate: validateSentence,
        trim: true
    }

    // Some other fields ...

  }]

  // Some other fields ...

});
```

For story of 20 sentences (the max), in order to get the entire story, for the first case we have to make 20 joins... Not so efficient...
But the second case likes more extensible, for example if I want to display just some random sentences, or update a sentence...

In my case I don't think sentences will be reused for others stories, and the story is writing sentence by sentence. I mean when a sentence is wrote, this is saved immediately in MongoDB.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a sentence make much sense in isolation?  Could you reuse a sentence more than once?  I think it is unlikely that a sentence would make much sense without the context of the story, and its very unlikely that you would want the reuse a sentence.

Therefore the story document should be composed of the sentence sub-documents.  I.e. you would have one collection (stories) and each story document will contain a collection of sentence sub-documents.  This would be the second schema you've shown.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks :-) And like @profesor79 said the retrieval will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

imho as long as the size of stories will fit in bson document limit, embed them into main document.

This will speed up retrieval process and also will enable ACID updates on document level.

Answer (score -1):

Sentences in Story because the max is only 20
MongoDB is "joinless" and it must be used as a "joinless"

You must use multiple collections for one to many relationships whenever the "many" is very large